# sendGrid not delivering emails from a node application hosted on vercel

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, vercel

I'm having issues sending emails via a node application hosted on vercel. I'm currently using sendGrid Email API with a verified domain. On development mode, it works fine, but when deployed to vercel, it will execute with the status of 200 but mail won't be delivered.
here is a screenshot of my code snippet for async and not async.

```js
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const sendMail = (mail) => {
  sgMail.send(mail).then(
    () => {},
    (error) => {
      console.error(error);

      if (error.response) {
        console.error(error.response.body);
      }
    }
  );
};
```

```js
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const sendMail = async(mail) => {
  await sgMail.send(mail).then(
    () => {},
    (error) => {
      console.error(error);

      if (error.response) {
        console.error(error.response.body);
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: Sounds like your Environment variable needs to be set remotely

Comment: With the way you have written the `sendMail` function, it will always return successfully in the location that it is called, which is likely why you are still seeing 200 responses (SendGrid itself returns a 202 for a successful request). I would suggest that perhaps you haven't set your API key in the Vercel environment as omeanwell also suggests. Can you check your Vercel logs to see whether any errors have been logged?

Comment: Thank so much, That was the issue, I already fixed it. Thanks for your help.